# como recortar el area dentro del rectangulo en el preview de la camara

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola Tengo dias tratando de resolver el siguiente asunto.

en la aplicacion que actualmente estoy desarrollando debo recortar el area dentro de rectangulo que muestro en el perview de la camara como se muestra a continuacion.

[image: app]

***¿que tengo?***

la clase preview

```
public class CapturePreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

public static Bitmap mBitmap;
SurfaceHolder holder;
static Camera mCamera;
private final Paint paint;



public CapturePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}

public static void takeAPicture(){

    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        }
    };
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
}
```

en mi fragment tab1_framgent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.ccsdeveloment.visitascontrol.CapturePreview
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!-- overlay - customize padding and stuff  -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="316dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect"
        android:padding="32dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Rect.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:dashGap="8dp"
    android:dashWidth="8dp" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

***¿que estoy intentando hacer?***

tratar que al capturar la foto ya sea por un boton o por ontouchevent se tome solo la seccion dentro del rectangulo. quisiera saber como es posible esto y ademas si se puede dejar el resto del area fuera del rectangulo una sombra transparente

un sombreado similar a esto

[image: transparent]

Gracias de antemano a aquellas personas que puedan ayudarme he estado leyendo algunas preguntas en la comunidad de stackoverflow en ingles he intentado algunas pero no he dado con una solucion... entiendo o creo entender que eso se logra con un surfaceview pero no entiendo bien su implementacion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Considera que:** Para que esto funcione, tienes que tener la misma relación aspecto de la vista previa, y de la camara.

Te comento como lo logré:

**1.-** No se que tal funcione este codigo en la API nativa de Android (Camera2), al menos yo la probé con la siguiente libreria:
 (https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) Es basicamente lo mismo que la API de google, solo que a un nivel mas avanzado para simplificar el uso de la camara.

**2.-** Es muy importante que ingreses esta linea del codigo: `cameraView.setCropOutput(true);` Con esto le estas indicando a la camara que recorte la imagen a la misma relación aspecto de la vista previa, esto te va a garantizar el funcionamiento en cualquier dispositivo.

**El codigo quedaría algo así:**

```
cameraView.setCropOutput(true);
    cameraView.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] jpeg) {
            super.onPictureTaken(jpeg);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg, 0, jpeg.length);
            int previewWidth = cameraView.getWidth();
            int previewHeight = cameraView.getHeight();
            int sizeImgX = bitmap.getWidth();
            int sizeImgY = bitmap.getHeight();
            float scaleX = ((float) (sizeImgX) / (float) (previewWidth)); 
            float scaleY = ((float) (sizeImgY) / (float) (previewHeight));
            int width = v.getWidth();      
            int height = v.getHeight();     
            int[] location = new int[2];
            v.getLocationInWindow(location);   
            int locationAtImageX = (int) (scaleX * location[0]);
            int locationAtImageY = (int) (scaleY * location[1]);
            int widthAtImageX = (int) (scaleX * width);
            int heightAtImageY = (int) (scaleY * height);
            Bitmap imagenOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg, 0, jpeg.length);
            Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
            rotationMatrix.postRotate(0);
            Bitmap imagenCortada = Bitmap.createBitmap(imagenOriginal, locationAtImageX, locationAtImageY, widthAtImageX, heightAtImageY, rotationMatrix, false);
        }
    });
```

Te explico:
Primero debes convertir el array de bytes a un bitmap:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg, 0, jpeg.length);
```

Obtienes las dimensiones de la vista previa:

```
int previewWidth = cameraView.getWidth();
int previewHeight = cameraView.getHeight();
```

Obtienes las dimensiones de la imagen:

```
int sizeImgX = bitmap.getWidth();
int sizeImgY = bitmap.getHeight();
```

Posteriormente obtienes la escala de la imagen con respecto a la vista previa:

```
float scaleX = ((float) (sizeImgX) / (float) (previewWidth));
float scaleY = ((float) (sizeImgY) / (float) (previewHeight));
```

Obtienes las dimensiones del rectangulo que quieres recortar:

```
int width = v.getWidth();       
int height = v.getHeight();
```

Donde 'v' es el rectangulo y es un objeto tipo View, en el layout yo lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/rectangle_focus"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera_rectangle_preview" />
```

Después obtienes la ubicación del rectángulo en la ventana:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
v.getLocationInWindow(location);
```

Y multiplicas dicha ubicación por la escala (esta será la posición de inicio desde donde se tiene que empezar a recortar la imagen):
    int locationAtImageX = (int) (scaleX * location[0]);
    int locationAtImageY = (int) (scaleY * location[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYKvZ.jpg));

Tambien necesitas obtener el tamaño que debera tener el recorte en X y en Y

```
int widthAtImageX = (int) (scaleX * width);
int heightAtImageY = (int) (scaleY * height);
```

Finalmente vas a obtener la imagen recortada en un bitmap mediante las siguientes lineas:

```
Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
                rotationMatrix.postRotate(0);
                Bitmap imagenCortada = Bitmap.createBitmap(imagenOriginal, locationAtImageX, locationAtImageY, widthAtImageX, heightAtImageY, rotationMatrix, false);
```

Resultado final:
[image]

[image]
Espero te funcione, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta ni te imaginas cuanto me has ayudado la verdad que tu respuesta se noto que estuvo muy bien trabajada, no habia agradecido antes porque esta adaptando esto a lo que necesitaba un millon de gracias.